# Getting status of 'Mobile network', status of autoconnect 3g after wifi drops

Tags: java, android, status, 3g

I'm just a beginner in Java figuring out this app for my android-phone.

What I'm looking for is to get the status of the mobile network autoconnect while wifi is on.

I've got the check if wifi is enabled and I can check if 3g is on, but 3g is disabled as wifi is 'master' of the connections and takes over/disables 3g.
My app has the possibility to shutdown wifi. But after shutting down wifi, 3g comes up. I want the status if the autoconnect to 3g is set in the device or something. After that I want to shut down the 3g connection, but that will be the next chapter. The status for this can be found in the settings Wireless and networks -> Mobile network [checkbox]

Did a lot of searching here and at google, but no luck. Maybe by asking here...

UPDATE:
Now looking into the system preferences. Finding out if status is stored in there.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution for above problem:

```
 public Boolean isMobileDataEnabled(){
    Object connectivityService = getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) connectivityService;

    try {
        Class<?> c = Class.forName(cm.getClass().getName());
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getMobileDataEnabled");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        return (Boolean)m.invoke(cm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem. It is the right method oppsite "setMobileDataEnabled".